# cannot replace \n from AnyHashable ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, pushwoosh

so I have my push notif payload with \n and after I received, it showing "hey \ntsshis"
tried to use replacingOccurences like this:

```
title = apnPayloadData!["alert"] as! String \\received it as hey \\ntsshis
title = title.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")
```

```
Push notification received: Optional([AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "hey \\ntsshis";
    badge = 1;
    sound = default;
}])
```

```
Optional([AnyHashable("sound"): default, AnyHashable("badge"): 1, AnyHashable("alert"): hey \ntsshis])
```

### UPDATE

It works on title.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression) the output is hey *nextline tsshis

but when I set the value to [String: Any] the output remain the same

Comment: can you attach actual payload what you are getting in Push?

Comment: Try to be a little more detailed with your question. You say you receive *"sample \nextline"* ... which, if you replace "\n" with a newline character, you would have one line of "sample " and one line of "extline". Is that what you're getting? Do you really just want to replace the slash "\" with a newline character? Is your `title.replacingOccurrences(...)` performing the replacement, but maybe your label is set to 1 line only so you don't see it?